# You don't have permission to access /schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd on this server

Tags: java

I am using spring framework in one of my application. It was working fine till now. But today in morning when I tried to run my application, it was throwing errors for not able to intialise spring framework. So I tried loading xsd files in the browser but in vain because it was showing forbidden page to me. And the page contains "**You don't have permission to access /schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd on this server**". I even tried loading 3.1 xsd, 2.5 xsd but not able to access any of them and showing same error page.

I know, I must download xsd and put them into my classpath but i haven't done and now i got this.

Can anyone please help me out of this? Or if any body has 3.0 xsd then can you please give it to me.

I want following xsds:

1. spring-beans-3.0.xsd
2. spring-context-3.0.xsd
3. spring-mvc-3.0.xsd

and xsds that are being called by the above one internally.

Thank you every one.

Answer (score 4):

The XSD files are included in the Spring JAR files, so you already have them. For example, spring-context-3.0.xsd is inside spring-context.jar, in the `org/springframework/context/config` package. The spring-beans.xsd is in spring-beans.jar (`org/springframework/beans/factory/xml` package) and I'll leave finding the last one as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it appears that the public schemas on the internet are unavailable. I found those spring-beans-2.5.0.xsd and save it in a directory of my app.

I changed the schema location to use the xsd on the path I gave it e.g. (WEB-INF/xml/spring-beans-2.5.0.xsd)

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.0.xsd

to

WEB-INF/xml/spring-beans-2.5.0.xsd

and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Public Schema was unavailable. It has been restored. Don't know where to look for status, but it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue today. The problem was that versions of XSD's and the Spring library in classpath were incompatible (3.0 vs 2.5.5 in my case). I fixed XSD versions in my spring XML's and it works fine now