# Spring Beans Schema no longer available on the Web?

Tags: java, spring

Visiting http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd in my browser produces a 403.

Visiting http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd in my browser returns a valid schema...

So what am I missing? Is this a transient issue? Or have the beans schemas moved somewhere else?

Comment: I also am missing it. And others http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?126584-HTTP-403-on-Schemas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem, it appears that the public schemas on the internet are unavailable.

I changed the schema location to use the xsd on the classpath e.g.

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
```

became:

```
classpath:/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
```

and that fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, the public schema is back at 11:00 am eastern on May 21.

Answer (score 1):

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680000/you-dont-have-permission-to-access-schema-beans-spring-beans-3-1-xsd-on-this-s).

You're not missing anything though, you have the correct url and they have a (presumably fixable) problem on their end.

In the long run however you should probably configure your app not to have dependecy to an http url, but rather store and refer the schemas locally.