# Can't load spring 3 schemas

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

i am using **Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE**
and today when building the project with maven, i am getting following errors in **appicationContext.xml** file:

```
 - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 
     'context:component-scan'.
 - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'context:annotation-
 config'.
 - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-
     driven'.
```

i tried to open the schema links:

- [Spring XML Beans Schema](http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd)
- [Spring Framework's declarative
  transaction management infrastructure](http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd)
- [Spring Framework's application
  context support](http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd)

but i always gets the page Forbidden !

here's how i am configuring the **applicationContext.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

please advise how to fix this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

seems that the public schemas are not available anymore, so i load the schemas from the jars on the classpath instead as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="  
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           classpath:/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
           classpath:/org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
           classpath:/org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems you are experiencing this problem: [Spring Beans Schema no longer available on the Web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681864) Are you defining `schemaLocation` explicitly?

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        ">
```

Comment: yes i am defining it explicitly, i edited my answer, i am using this approach for very long time, but it stopped working today i don't know why.

Comment: @Msaleh: see the link I am refering to, you are not the only one.