# How to map Spring XSD from local environment

Tags: java, spring

I have downloaded list of Spring XSD files in local environment in order to remove the online / internet dependency.

Now want to map those files in ApplicationContext. How to map the XSD files with ApplicationContext.xml?

Comment: I think the accepted answer on this post is what you are after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687511/cant-load-spring-3-schemas

Comment: Sidenote: Aren't the xsds part of the jars and would not need to be downloaded?

Comment: @Scorpio The accepted answer on the post I have provided does exactly that.